# Are WSDL's like spring dispatch servlet?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, wsdl

im trying to understand where WSDL's fit in, in a typical web service backend application. i am coming from a Spring background and in my experience so far, in Spring, each url request gets mapped to a specific controller class via a dispate servlet running in the web container. you can specify which url matches a given controller via xml config or from annotations.

is using a WSDL the same thing as using an xml config file to map url requests to java objects?

Thanks in advance. im moving from Spring to standard j2ee/EJB3.

Comment: It's just "Java EE" - "J2EE" hasn't been used since Java 4. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Nomenclature.2C_standards.2C_and_specifications

Answer (score 1):

WSDL is just a description of Web Service interface, most Web Service systems generate those descriptions on fly like for example when you create asmx web services you can generate WSDL on fly by typing http://yourhost/yourwebcontext/yourwebservicename.asmx?wsdl and it will return you the description of that web service. Then you can use a tools that generate stub proxies for coding using those descriptions automatically, for example in Visual Studio when you add an Web Service Reference those operations are done automatically

Answer (score 0):

No, WSDLs are not like a dispatch servlet.

A WSDL file is a **description of a web service** (SOAP, REST, etc.). A WSDL can (theoretically) be used by anyone to generate executable code which consumes the web service described by that WSDL.

From [the WSDL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wsdl/info):

> "WSDL" stands for "Web Services Description Language." It is an XML language used to describe a web service to code that wishes to consume it. It describes the messages sent and received, the possible faults, and the communication and security requirements.

From [WSDL Essentials](http://oreilly.com/catalog/webservess/chapter/ch06.html):

> In a nutshell, WSDL represents a contract between the service requestor and the service provider, in much the same way that a Java interface represents a contract between client code and the actual Java object. The crucial difference is that WSDL is platform- and language-independent and is used primarily (although not exclusively) to describe SOAP services.
>
> Using WSDL, a client can locate a web service and invoke any of its publicly available functions. With WSDL-aware tools, you can also automate this process, enabling applications to easily integrate new services with little or no manual code. WSDL therefore represents a cornerstone of the web service architecture, because it provides a common language for describing services and a platform for automatically integrating those services.

Comment: Ahh ok so a front end can simply auto generate code based on wsdl's? Or is it purely for a human person to just use as a reference. much like java docs api

Comment: Jon Skeet is only "human" who reads WSDLs, and that's only because it's faster than letting his computer do it ;-). But in all seriousness, WSDLs are generated by computers, and meant to be consumed by computers. WSDLs are decidedly not meant for regular human consumption.

Comment: I see. ok so in a typical J2EE project that has a webervice. how does the j2ee app know how to map a particular url request to a particular class? in spring its doen using the dispatch servlett looking at either your controllers mapped in xml against the url, or your annotations in your controllers.

Comment: I think I see where you're getting caught up. You're right about using the deployment descriptor or annotations to describe the servlets, the URL mappings, etc. within a Java EE app. But you wouldn't give your deployment descriptor to clients (consumers) of your web service, since it's meaningless to them - it's not relevant information. On the other hand, WSDLs are a description of your web service _from the outside_. The servlet container doesn't use a WSDL to describe or specify the internal workings of a web service that it's running.

Comment: ahh ok its begining to make sense. WSDL's are like API documentations that describe the web services available to them